# Find duplicates using parcel number and updated their status. SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, sql-update

I have a problem with duplicate records in a SQL Server 2014 database.

Users get a small postcard with a parcel number printed on them. 
The postcard also shows a link to a simple form that they can use,  to register their parcel.

The form unfortunately does not have any type of validation, to ensure that the same parcel does not get submitted more than once. 
I currently have no control on the web form, and I am not sure how long will take for the responsible team to implement validation on it.

So I have to come up with a routine to deactivate the duplicate records, and keep only one.

This has to be a query that process a bulk of records, no tokens passed to the routine.

When the web form gets submitted, it creates a record id in sequential order, and assigns an application status of "Registered'. 
I think that the way to correct this, would be to take highest record id value per parcel, and that would be the one to keep, the rest, will have to be deactivated.

Deactivate the non most recent records putting a rec_status of "I"
Set APPLICATION_STATUS to 'Closed' to the non most recent records

The query I use, returns 4 columns: Record Id, Parcel Number, Record Status, and Application Status

```
SELECT 
    B.[RECORD_ID], 
    B.[PARCEL_NBR], 
    B.[RECORD_STATUS],  -- The value of this column would be "I" for the duplicate records.
    B.[APPLICATION_STATUS]
FROM 
    A_TABLE A
INNER JOIN B_TABLE B 
    ON A.PARCEL_NBR = B.PARCEL_NBR
    AND (A.APPLICATION_STATUS IS NULL
    OR B.APPLICATION_STATUS = 'Registered');
```

Initial Output:

```
RECORD_ID   PARCEL_NBR      RECORD_STATUS   APPLICATION_STATUS
REC-00081   0608012098      A               Registered
REC-00082   0608012098      A               Registered
REC-00083   0608012098      A               Registered
```

Expected Output:

```
RECORD_ID   PARCEL_NBR      RECORD_STATUS   APPLICATION_STATUS
REC-00081   0608012098      I               Closed  - this record got updated
REC-00082   0608012098      I               Closed  - this record got updated
REC-00083   0608012098      A               Registered
```

I think that perhaps a cursor might be part of the solution? Honestly I am not sure. I kindly ask for your help.

Comment: which columns are coming from A_TABLE and which are coming from B_TABLE?

Comment: Hi Sentinel - I updated the query. Those are all table B columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions and `case` logic:

```
SELECT B.[RECORD_ID],  B.[PARCEL_NBR], 
       (CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B.PARCEL_NBR ORDER BY B.RECORD_ID DESC) > 1
             THEN 'I' ELSE B.[RECORD_STATUS]
         END) as RECORD_STATUS,
       (CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B.PARCEL_NBR ORDER BY B.RECORD_ID DESC) > 1
             THEN Closed  - this record got updated ELSE B.APPLICATION_STATUS
         END) as APPLICATION_STATUS,
    B.[]
FROM A_TABLE A JOIN
     B_TABLE B 
     ON A.PARCEL_NBR = B.PARCEL_NBR AND
       (A.APPLICATION_STATUS IS NULL OR B.APPLICATION_STATUS = 'Registered');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what role A_TABLE plays in this, but this may give you what you want:

```
update B_TABLE
   set record_Status = 'I'
     , application_status = 'Closed  - this record got updated'
 where record_status = 'A'
   and application_status = 'Registered'
   and record_id <> (select max(record_id)
                       from B_TABLE b
                      where b.parcel_nbr = B_TABLE.parcel_nbr
                        and b.record_status = 'A'
                        and b.application_status = 'Registered');
```

Comment: Hello Gordon, and Sentinel. Thank you for sharing your ideas and help. I will work on adapting your queries to mine and see if I can make it work. I will report shortly. Thank you.